# (Google Maps API) Como obtener *coordenadas* de un array de Markers en Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-v3

Con mi código creo un arreglo de Markers de Google Maps, en donde necesito el *puntoA* y el *puntoB* para pintar una ruta en el mapa y calcular los kilometros.

```
function addMarker(location, addrs, counter) {

            if(counter <= 2){ 

                    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: location,
                    map: exports.map,
                    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                    title: "Point: "+ counter + "Address:" + addrs
                });

                exports.markers.push(marker);

            }else{
                calculateRoute();
                alert("Ya terminaste de seleccionar la ruta");

            }
        } // Sets the map on all markers in the array.
```

Una vez que capturo mis 2 Markes, quisiera mostrar y pintar la ruta entre el puntoA y el puntoB.

Entonces, hice una function llamada *calculateRute()* en donde leo mi arreglo de Markers y obtengo las *position* (que son mis coordenadas del PUNTOA y el PUNTOB), lo asigno a otro arreglo en donde solo quiero poner las coordenadas y las muestro en un ALERT(), hasta acá todo bien.

```
function calculateRoute(){
        
        for (var i = 0; i < exports.markers.length; i++) {
            maping[i] = exports.markers[i].position;
            //show my coordenates
            alert(maping[i]);
        }

        var request = {
            origin: maping[0],
            destination: maping[1],
            travelMode: 'DRIVING'
        }

        directionsService.route(request, function(result, status){

            if (status=="OK") {

                directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);
            }
        })
    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando vamos a *request* y le pasamos los atributos del ARRAY de COORDENADAS (puntoA y puntoB) por su posición a ORIGIN y DESTINATION, NO ME MUESTRA NADA.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No logro obtener como tal las coordenadas y asignarlas, no entiendo porque no funciona asi como lo estoy manejando.

Lógico, al final solo pinta mis dos Markers y no me pinta la ruta porque no obtengo las coordenadas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Que te muestra `maping` si haces un console.log después del for? Has probado a iniciarlo antes del for?

Comment: {lat: ƒ, lng: ƒ}
lat: ƒ ()
lng: ƒ ()
__proto__: Object

*ESO ES LO QUE ME MUESTRA*

Comment: 0: _.I
lat: ƒ ()
arguments: null
caller: null
length: 0
name: ""
prototype: {constructor: ƒ}
__proto__: ƒ ()
[[FunctionLocation]]: js?key=YOUR_KEY&libraries=places:83
[[Scopes]]: Scopes[3]
0: Closure (_.I) {b: -122.40583123779298, a: 37.751628871871425}
1: Closure {_: {…}, ua: ƒ, za: ƒ, Fa: ƒ, Ga: ƒ, …}
2: Global {parent: Window, opener: null, top: Window, length: 1, frames: Window, …}
lng: ƒ ()
__proto__: Object
1: _.I {lat: ƒ, lng: ƒ}
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0) 

COMO PUEDES VER, HE NOTADO QUE LAS COORDENADAS si las contiene, pero estan dentro de SCOPE.

Comment: y si manejas tus cordenadas de A y B al recorrerlas por separado,se podria?

Comment: Ya hice 2 arreglos, ya logro obtener ambas COORDENADAS, ahora no me PINTA la RUTA, ya subo ahorita mi situación actual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logre obtener la longitud y la latitud haciendo 2 arreglos, no creo que sea la mejor opción, pero me ha funcionado hasta ahora:

```
function calculateRoute(){

            var lang = [];
            var lat = [];

            for (var i = 0; i < exports.markers.length; i++) {
                lat[i] = exports.markers[i].getPosition().lat();
                lang[i] = exports.markers[i].getPosition().lng();
                //alert("LAT: " + lat[i] + " LANG: " + lang[i]);
            }

            var location_a, location_b;

            location_a = lat[0] +","+ lang[0];
            location_b = lat[1] +","+ lang[1];
            

            var request = {
                origin: location_a,
                destination: location_b,
                travelMode: 'DRIVING'
            }

            directionsService.route(request, function(result, status){

                if (status=="OK") {
                    setMapOnAll(null);
                    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
                    directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);
                    // Calculate and display the distance between markers
                    calculateDistance(location_a, location_b);
                }
            })
        }
```